# Regular expression to match ) under certain conditions

Tags: regex

I am trying to match ) if there is a ( and two numbers to the left of it.

Example "(55)"
I want to match ) in "(55)"

I do not want to match "(hello world 55)"

I currently have the following as my regex:

```
     \(\d+\)
```

It matches "(55)" but I just want the ) in it. Is there a way to get a certain character by placement in a regex?  Or do you have a better solution?

Comment: `\(\d+\K\)`, `(?<=\(\d+)\)`, etc. There are a lot of solutions and workarounds.

Comment: You need to escape the parentheses

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I was going to answer this and saw your comment, why don't you post it as an answer. It's a nice answer since it can have `\K` or look behind

Comment: Please try this [`(?<=\(\d{2})\)`](https://regex101.com/r/KROBYi/2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to match what you want.

For instance, you can use `\K` to rest the previous match:

```
\(\d+\K\)
```

Using positive lookbehind

```
(?<=\(\d+)\)
```

Also capturing the content for the match

```
\(\d+(\))
```

Answer (score 0):

Flutter and all Languages supported

Insert all Special Character, Number, Lowercase & Uppercase

condition 1: Must Length of word 8
condition 2: Insert any of above given list (Not Must in all type)

```
r'^([a-zA-Z].)*.{8,}$' ,
```

Must Insert Atleast One in Above given list,

```
r'^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]+!@#\$&*~{8,}$',
```